# Pocket API: how to obtain the Access token

Tags: php, jquery, api, pocket

I'm trying to produce a web page showing my list of "Read it later" articles stored in Pocket, using their API, and following the [directions published on their Documentation](http://getpocket.com/developer/docs/authentication).

Step 1: have a consumer key.
I created the Pocket App, and have the consumer_key.

Step 2: get an access token. This is where i get stuck. I'm supposed to send a POST request with the `consumer_key` and the `redirect_uri`, which i fail to understand. 
My script sits at domain.com/pocket/index.php, which is where i would like that the token be sent, so i'd assume the `redirect_uri` is that url. But in the documentation, they use something like "`pocketapp12388:authorizationFinished`" which does not look like a url to me.

In any case, whichever i use I get a "400 Bad Request", which means the redirect_uri is incorrect. What am i doing wrong?

Here is a small demo on [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/pixeline/6DHyP/)

Answer (score 2):

if you need access token use https://github.com/jshawl/pocket-oauth-php
open config.php put you consumer_key and redirect_uri (path.to/callback.p h p) and start path.to/connect.p h p
sorry for my english))

Answer (score 2):

Well, nothing is wrong with your query. It doesn't work on JSFiddle because JSFiddle sends the **XMLHttpRequest** from a different domain to another domain, which is not allowed.

Here is the error message you're getting if you check your console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://getpocket.com/v3/oauth/request. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.
```

More info on this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20035319/800387

To test your query, you can use Chrome extensions like **POSTMan REST Client**: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en